# WD 500gb Hard Drive Reads on my computer Shows No data

Tags: hard-drive

Hi i just tried plugging in my WD 500g Hard Drive when it just shows me the drive with no data. I ran a cksdsk/e and it says Invalid Parameters. It also asks me to format disk.

Can anyone help solve this problem?

Comment: You need to format the disk to use it... I'm assuming this is a new disk?

Comment: That is not correct (assuming it came formatted which is almost always the case)

Comment: I've never seen a preformatted HDD before... How would they even decide what to format it as?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command will take a while, but try `chkdsk I: /r /f /v /x` where `I:` should be replaced with your drive letter.

Comment: ok running it now seems to be working will let you know when i finish. thanks

Comment: hey they Soando, just curious i know you said it would take a while but any idea of how long. i have had it running for 6 hours now and it seems to be stuck in stage 4 not sure if it just takes a long time to go thru all the files or if it has froze. also what would happen if i prematurely unpluged the hard disk before it was finished?

Comment: ok so i wasn't able to finish yesterday. trying again today but now it says "the type of the file system is RAW. CHKDSK is not available for RAW drives. Do you know of anything else i can do?

Comment: At some point you messed up the formating on the drive (between today and yesterday). Now you have to forma

Comment: ok couldn't see your last msg lol. stopped at forma... but was looking around and saw something called "diskpart.exe clean" now it sounds to me like this will format my drive. which it looks like i need to do anyways my biggest concern is the photos i have on the drive. I do have Recuva which is suppose to recover data from formatted drives but have never used it before. any more pointers lol! thanks again for your help

Comment: Your data will not be lost during the format, don't worry about it

Comment: ok but when i click format it says "Warning: Formatting will erase ALL data on this disk" lol

Comment: You should be doing a "Quick" format. In that case, only the file table will get wiped.

Comment: do you think Recuva will be able to recover the data or do u know of another program that is better?

Comment: Recuva is fine.

Comment: ok thanks gonna go for it. wish me luck lol. will let you know how it turns out. thanks again for all the help =)

Comment: lol ok says windows was unable to complete the format

Comment: Try later, but that probably means that the drive is toast

Comment: well thats a bummer

Comment: one more question i ran a disk part clean on the drive. was told that would allow me to format but now can't see the drive. whats the best way to format now

Comment: If you see the drive, you can try reading it from another PC, but like I said, its probably toast.